# I ran across this in a 1621 fencing manual and I'm stumped

Tags: translation

Any help with the translation?

Or any ideas on what's going on?

It's PDF page 38 in the document.

Entire document: 
http://hroarr.com/manuals/other/pistofilo-bonaventura-oplomachia-1621.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Note that [general translation requests](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are off-topic unless you are more specific. So please try to reword your question.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

La pagina specifica sembra riferirsi a diverse unità di misura. I "diti" mi fanno pensare ad una forma arcaica per "dita".
Piede sembra un'altra unità di misura. Altra unità di misura il palmo.
Si parla di "mezzo piede", "un quarto di piede", etc.
Si specifica anche "piede Romano" (credo che Romº sia una abbreviazione di Romano, anche perché a metà della pagina dice "piede Romº o di Parigi).
L'oncia e il punto (plurale = "punti") credo che compaiono come sotto multipli.
Il Porto e il Galeano credo siano cognomi di autori a cui si fa riferimento, mentre Euclide è il filosofo greco.

Comment: Yes, I have a feeling that the preceding section would need to be translated for this to make sense. And my Italian has a way to go, so this maybe shelved for a while. I have no idea where ounces would come into it, but punto maybe a thrust.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Fabio!

Comment: As for the *oncia*, this word, just like its English analogue “ounce”, meant originally “one twelfth” of any unit (of length or weight, mostly). You can see a little more in section 2.a of this [dictionary entry](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oncia/) (in Italian). Here, in particular, the second figure says *Oncia over Pollice*, that is, “Ounce, or Inch”; and the same figure shows an ounce to be one-third of something (a *palmo*) which its caption describes as *Quarta parte del piede romano* (One fourth of the Roman foot). So this particular ounce/inch is indeed one-twelfth of a foot.

Comment: And, by the way, the word “inch” itself has the same origin as “ounce” and *oncia*.